# Dictionary with arrays as values

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

Not sure if this is a good idea after all, but having a dictionary with arrays as values, such as

```
DF = {'z_eu': array([127.45064758, 150.4478288 , 150.74781189, -98.3227338 , -98.25155681, -98.24993753]), 
      'Process': array(['initStep', 'Transportation', 'Transportation', 'Transportation', 'Transportation', 'phot']),
      'Creator': array(['SynRad', 'SynRad', 'SynRad', 'SynRad', 'SynRad', 'SynRad']) }
```

I need to do a selection of the numeric data (`z_eu`) based on values of the other two keys.

One workaround I came up with so far, was to extract the arrays and iterate through them, thereby creating another array which contains the valid data.

```
proc = DF['Process']; z= DF['z_eu']; creat = DF['Creator']
data = [z for z,p,c in zip(z, proc,creat) if (p == 'initStep') and c=='SynRad' ]
```

But somehow this seems to me as effort which can be completely avoided by dealing more intelligently with the dictionary in the first place? Also, the `zip()` takes a long time as well.

I know that dataframes are a valid alternative but unfortunately, since I'm dealing with strings, pandas appears to be too slow.

Any hints are most welcome!

Comment: So by array you mean numpy ndarray? Right now, the values of your dict are arrays, not the keys. Also, did you have a look at numpy functions like e.g. `where`? Another way to go might be a `pandas` `DataFrame`...

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Yes, the values are arrays, not the keys - I corrected that. I could have another detailed look into the numpy functions indeed. Your proposed approach seems to come close to a solution. Let me check a bit further.
I tried to use a `DataFrame` instead but it is fairly slow since I'm dealing with strings ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit simpler, using conditional slicing you could write

```py
data = DF['z_eu'][(DF['Process'] == 'initStep') & (DF['Creator'] == 'SynRad')]
```

...or still using `zip`, you could simplify to

```py
data = [z for z, p, c in zip(*DF.values()) if p == 'initStep' and c == 'SynRad']
```

Basically also conditional slicing, using a `pandas` `DataFrame`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(DF)
data = df.loc[(df['Process'] == 'initStep') & (df['Creator'] == 'SynRad'), 'z_eu']
print(data)
# 0    127.450648
# Name: z_eu, dtype: float64
```

In principle I'd say there's nothing wrong with handling `numpy` arrays in a `dict`. You'll have a lot of flexibility and sometimes operations are more efficient if you do them straight in `numpy` (you could even utilize `numba` for purely numerical, expensive calculations) - but if that is not needed and you're fine with basically a n*m table, `pandas` dfs are nice and convenient.

If your dataset is large and you want to perform many look-ups as the one shown, you might not want to perform those on strings. To improve performance, you could e.g. come up with unique IDs (integers) for each 'Process' or 'Creator' from the example. You'll just need to be able to map those back to the original strings, so keep that data as well.

Comment: Thanks for also adding the `pandas` option, although I already tried to use it (to the best of my abilities) and again, it's performance is nasty.
However, the solution using the dictionary seems to be an approach worthwhile following.

Comment: @Number42: yeah what I forgot to mention is that strings are not numpy's nor pandas's "natural habitat". made an edit to clarify ;-)

Comment: Yes, I thought about having ID's for the strings as well. But the lookup is not so much a problem than the import itself. Using `uproot` to import data from a `ROOT` `TTree` works flawless on any numerical data but strings are really nasty to deal with. Need to find another way ...

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through one array and via the index get the right element

```
z_eu = DF['z_eu']
process = DF['Process']
creator = DF['Creator']

result = []
for i in range(len(z_eu)):
    if process[i] == 'initStep' and creator[i] == 'SynRad':
        result.append(z_eu[i])
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. But I'd rather avoid conventional loops since they tend to be not the best solution in terms of performance once the arrays grow really long.